# Longest common subsequence for 3+ sequences in c

Tags: c, lcs

I have already written the part of LCS.
I want to know If I give N(N>3) ,that means how many set of input. 
Like this :
**Input**:
 
4  ab  abc  abcd  abcde
**Output**:
3
Just find the longest of those lcs(3 sequences a part)
ab abc abcd->ab->2
abc abcd abcde->abc->3
3>2
My thinking is that every number of set just use the way of 3 sequences then find the bigest one.
But I dont't know how to do it or any better way?
This is a part of my code:

```
#define EQUAL(x,y,z) ((x)==(y)&&(y)==(z))
```

```
int main(){

int set;
int longest;

while (scanf("%d", &set) != EOF){
    while (set){
        scanf("%s", c1);
        set--;
        scanf("%s", c2);
        set--;
        scanf("%s", c3);
        set--;
        longest = LCS(strlen(c1), strlen(c2), strlen(c3));
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

LCS:

```
int LCS(int c1_length, int c2_length, int c3_length)
    {
        memset(lcs, 0, N*N);
        int i;
        int j;
        int k;
        for (i = 1; i <= c1_length; i++)
            for (j = 1; j <= c2_length; j++)
                for (k = 1; k <= c3_length; k++)
                {
            if (EQUAL(c1[i], c2[j], c3[k]))
                lcs[i][j][k] = lcs[i - 1][j - 1][k - 1] + 1;
            else
                lcs[i][j][k] = max(lcs[i - 1][j][k], lcs[i][j - 1][k], lcs[i][j][k - 1]);
                }
        return lcs[i - 1][j - 1][k - 1];
    }
```

Thanks everybody~ I have solved this question by using 2d array to store the sequence.

Comment: Have you looked at the `strstr` function to test if the substring exists and then a simple pointer increment until the strings differ to get a length for the match in each. Might be less error prone than `i,j,k` index manipulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An iterative procedure may be a way to solve your problem. But the subsequence of maximum length can start everywhere in the first string. As a new string is introduced in the procedure, keeping the current maximum subsequence is not sufficient. Here is a way to store an array of strings :

```
char s[nb][N]; //nb strings of max length N-1
```

You may try to keep trace of an array `int seqlen[j]`, as long as the first string `s[0]`, storing the length of the maximum common subsequence starting at place `j` in the first string `s[0]`.

Initialization : if `s[0]` is the only string, then the length of the maximum common subsequence starting at place `j` is `strlen(s[0])-j`

Introducing a new string `s[i]` : `seqlen[j]` needs to be updated (for all j).
Create a copy `temp` of the current substring of `s[0]`, starting at `s[0][j]` of length `seqlen[j]`. This is where `strstr(temp,s[i])` may be used. While `strstr()` returns NULL and `seqlen[j]>0`, reduce the size of `temp` by introducing null-terminating character `'\0'` at the end of `temp` and decrease `seqlen[j]`. At the end, `seqlen[j]` is the length of the maximum common subsequence starting at place `j` in the first string `s[0]`.

The final step is to take the maximum of `seqlen[j]`, that is the length of the largest common substring. This substring starts at the corresponding position `j` in `s[0]`

Memory footprint and algorithmic refinement : find the smallest string and use it as `s[0]`.

Algorithmic refinement : the procedure to update `seqlen[j]` may be updated using a binary search method.

Memory refinement : allocate memory for the array of strings using `malloc()`, while taking account of the exact length of strings.

Comment: I think I ues the similar way.But I still didn't use the strstr().:p
Thank you!